# Modifying a letter with scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters

I'm writing my first letter with LaTeX, and I need some help:

1. I need to put the address of the sender on the upper left side of the page.
2. Put my name in the lower right part of the page.
3. I would like to have the date immediately under the receiver name, separated with some space. Can someone help me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{40mm}
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{110mm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Name \\ Of \\ Receiver}

\opening{Dear...,} 
Text....
\closing{Best regards,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the letter style seems fairly elementary and you're merely concerned with the layout, I would suggest going with a standard `article` document class, and set the document according to your requirements as-is. This avoid fiddling with length and alignment settings that may be obscure for a non-user of the particular document class in question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\pagestyle{empty}% No page number
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
\begin{document}
% Sender address
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  1234-56 Random Rd \\
  Randomville, 78901 \\
  RANDOMLAND
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Random Person,% Recipient

\smallskip

\today% Date

\medskip

\lipsum[1-3]% Beautiful letter

\leavevmode\hfill
\begin{tabular}{r@{}}
  Best regards, \\ \\ \\
  Random Randofsky
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

More detail about the layout can be added, of course.